# calculate whether regression coefficient is statistically significant in R

Tags: r, statistics, regression, standard-error

I have results from a regression analysis conducted with another program and I would like to test with R whether they are significant. I know that ls.diag() calculates standard errors and t-tests for regression results, but it requires a very specific input format (i.e., the result of lsfit()), so I don't think I can use that. Is there any function in r that calculates standard errors and t-tests for regression analysis that allows me to simply give the relevant coefficients to the function by hand?

Comment: It is not clear from your description what you have got from the "other program", but I am quite sure that it is much less work to go back to the original data and do everything in R.

Comment: depends.  If the OP has the coefficients and their standard errors then it's easy (although she mentions ("calculat[ing] standard errors").  We do need to know what the other program has produced, though.  If it's just the coefficients then the answer is "no".

Comment: These are results from a regression analysis that controls for phylogenetic relatedness among the taxa in the sample. R has a function (pgls() in caper) to do this, but it doesn't work for part of my data. From the OP I have coefficients and trait variance, but no coefficient variance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not so sure this is what you're lookin for, but here's a guideline

```
# this is a model obtained from ?lm 
ctl <- c(4.17,5.58,5.18,6.11,4.50,4.61,5.17,4.53,5.33,5.14)
trt <- c(4.81,4.17,4.41,3.59,5.87,3.83,6.03,4.89,4.32,4.69)
group <- gl(2,10,20, labels=c("Ctl","Trt"))
weight <- c(ctl, trt)
lm.D9 <- lm(weight ~ group)
summary(lm.D9) this is our target
```

Suppose we only have the regression coefficients, its standard errors and the sample size

```
beta <- coef(lm.D9)
errorBeta <- summary(lm.D9)$coefficients[,2]
n <- length(weight) # the sample size
k <- length(beta) # number of regression parameters
```

I think this is your case, if you don't have the coefficient standard errors, then you have to estimate them, it's quite easy.

Once you have the regression coefficients and its standard errors, one can estimate the t-stat:

```
t_stats <- beta/errorBeta
```

The rule of thumb states that if |t_stats| >= 2 then the coefficient is statistically  significant at 5% level. But if you want to know the p-value, then use:

```
pt(abs(t_stats), n-k, lower.tail=FALSE)*2
```

If p-values > 0.05 then the associated coefficients are not statistical significant at that level.

All what you need is knowing the coefficients, its standard errors and the sample size. Otherwise you won't do it.

Comment: Thanks Jilber! That sounds exactly like what I would need. You are right, I just have the coefficients, nothing else. I know that the coefficient standard errors are the square roots of the variance of the regression coefficients. However, I don't have the variance of the regression coefficients - is this a problem? You say estimating them is easy, could you tell me how?

Comment: First you have to estimate the variance of the residuals, it's simply the residuals sum of squares divided by n-k, using this result and assuming you have the data set, then only multiply the variance of the  residuals by the design matrix {(X'X)⁻¹}. It's weird you don't have the standard errors, if you have the estimatiion you must have the standard errors. Anyway you can read any econometric textbook in order to find proper instructions.

Comment: Thanks Jilber, that helps a lot!